# I have a basic damage/armor system and I want to reduce the incoming damage by how much the armor is

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

As I said in the title.I want the incoming damaged to be reduced by how much armor i have (e.g damage is 30 so if i do 1/3 * armor = some number)But i cant figure out where i should put this.Does it need to be inside my enemy Script where the amount of damage is comming form?Or inside my PlayerStats Script where the Incoming damage is taken out of my health?
My players script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class PlayerStats : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int armor = 5;
    public int currentLevel;
    public int currentXP;
    public int MaxLevel;

    public int[] ExpToNextLevel;


    public void SavePlayer(){
        SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
    }
    public void LoadPlayer(){
        PlayerData data = SaveSystem.loadPlayer();
        currentLevel = data.level;
        healthMax = data.MaxHealth;
        attackDamage = data.Damage;
    }
    void Awake(){
        currentLevel = 1;
        currentXP = 0;
    }
    void Start(){
        health = healthMax;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(healthMax);
        
        ExpToNextLevel = new int [MaxLevel+1];
        ExpToNextLevel[1] = 15;
        for(int i =2;i<MaxLevel;i++){
            ExpToNextLevel[i] = Mathf.RoundToInt(ExpToNextLevel[i-1]*1.2f);
        }
    }
    void Update(){
        if(Time.time >= nextAttackTime){

        
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
            Attack();
            nextAttackTime = Time.time +1f/attackRate;
        }
        }
        FindObjectOfType<StatsUI>().UpdatePlayerStatus();
        
    }
     public void AddExp(int amount){
        currentXP += amount;
        if(currentXP >= ExpToNextLevel[currentLevel]){
            LevelUp();
        }
        }

        private void LevelUp(){
            currentLevel++;
            healthMax = Mathf.RoundToInt(healthMax * 1.2f);
            attackDamage = Mathf.CeilToInt(attackDamage * 1.2f);

            
        }

        //HEALTH SYSTEM

         public HealthBarSystem healthBar;
    public event EventHandler OnHealthChanged;
    public int health;
    public int healthMax;

    
    public void Damage(int damageAmount){
        health -= damageAmount-1/3*armor;
        healthBar.SetHealth(health);
        if(health < 0) health =0;
        if(OnHealthChanged != null) OnHealthChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public void Heal(int healAmount){
        health += healAmount;
        healthBar.SetHealth(health);
        if (health > healthMax)health = healthMax;
        if(OnHealthChanged != null) OnHealthChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider){
        if(collider.transform.tag=="Potion"){
            Debug.Log("Your Halth has risen");
            Heal(20);
        }
    }
    public Transform AttackPoint;
    public float AttackRange = 0.5f;
    public LayerMask enemyLayers;
    public Animator animator;
    public int attackDamage = 10;
    public float attackRate =2f;
    float nextAttackTime = 0f;

    
    void Attack(){
        animator.SetTrigger("Attack");

        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackPoint.position, AttackRange, enemyLayers);

        foreach(Collider2D  enemy in hitEnemies){
            enemy.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().TakeDamage(attackDamage);
            Debug.Log("We hit"+ enemy.name);  
        }
    }
    

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected(){
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(AttackPoint.position, AttackRange);
    }

  
}
```

Enemy Script here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySlime : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int armor;
    bool IsDead = false;
    private PlayerStats playerLevelSystem;
    public int expToGive = 15;
    public int damage;
    public Animator animator;
    public int speed;
    [SerializeField]
    Transform player;
    [SerializeField]
    float agroRange;
   Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    private int health;

    void Awake(){
      
    }
   void Start(){
    armor = GetComponent<PlayerStats>().armor;
    health = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().health;
    playerLevelSystem = FindObjectOfType<PlayerStats>();
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
      
     
   }

  
    void Update(){
        health = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().health;
          float distToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

        if (transform.position.y > 0) {
      transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z);
   }
        if(distToPlayer < agroRange && health > 0){
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,player.position,speed*Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (health <= 0){
          rb2d.velocity = Vector3.zero;          
        }
        if (health <= 0 && IsDead == false){
          ExpToPlayer();
        }
        
        
        
}

    private void ExpToPlayer(){
      playerLevelSystem.AddExp(expToGive);
      Debug.Log("Xp Given");
      IsDead = true;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
      if(col.gameObject.tag == ("Player")){
        col.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerStats>().Damage(damage-((1/3)*armor));
      }
    }

    
    
   
}
```

Comment: It should separate module. A class, which holds logic and returns dealt damage. Easy to test, easy to apply to some interface be it human, dog or door.

Comment: So to sum up.I need to make a separate Script that will handle the incoming damage from the enemy and in that script i need to aply my damage - armor values?

Comment: Just calculate - application should be performed on some interface, like IHealth or something, rather than on concrete entity "EnemySlime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to separate this logic into three different interfaces:

```
public interface IWeapon {} //deals damage
public interface IArmor {} //reduces damage
public interface IBuff {} //modifies entire plot into something else, for example, swapping armor/damage, or identifiyng damage type, or deal/heal damage, or make some special effect like burning, frozen, chilled, etc. Or just specifying you fighting on EXTREME HARDCORE, thus reducing your armor to nothing.
```

Then I would define interface which calculates what happens when hit:

```
public interface IDamage {} //identifies what happens, it can deal zero damage and flip player upside down, froze him, or whatever.
public inteface IDamageSystem
{
    IDamage Calculate(IWeapon weapon, IArmor armor, params IBuff[] buffs);
}
```

Ideally, IWeapon/IArmor is a buff itself, so can be omitted, you just pass a bunch of conditions and calculate damage accordingly.

Then something like apply should be present on your "healthy" entites, which finally just modifies state of entity and nothing else:

```
public interface ILivingBeing
{
    void ApplyDamage(IDamage damage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.I will try those things you said,althou im a newbie in C# but i will try.